# I want to modify an object executed by a Windows service using WinForms C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, windows-services, task

I have a program that runs a service like the code below:

```
public static void runService()
{
    var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
    {
        x.Service<StayingAlive>(s =>
        {
            s.ConstructUsing(stayingAlive =>
            {
                sa = new StayingAlive();
                return sa;
            });
            s.WhenStarted(stayingAlive => stayingAlive.Start());
            s.WhenStopped(stayingAlive => stayingAlive.Stop());
        });

        x.RunAsLocalSystem();
        x.SetServiceName("SimpleService");
        x.SetDisplayName("SimpleService");
        x.SetDescription("This is the simple service");
    });
    int exitCodeValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
    Environment.ExitCode = exitCodeValue;
}
```

This method is called in the main .cs file. Then, I have the class `StayingAlive` with many attributes and methods.

Now, I want to execute at the same time a WinForm so that with a Button I modify an attribute in the class `StayingAlive()`.

Is there any possibility? I have tried using `Task`s or `Thread`s but I get stuck.

Comment: this sounds very much like a X/Y problem. What is it you are actually trying to accomplish? Changing attributes would involve modifying the assembly while it is running, and that is just not feasible.

Comment: Services generally run under an account that does not have access to the display.  If you want a form that communicates with a service, they are different processes, and will need to use some form of RPC.

Comment: I would say that storing those attribute in some shared place (like database) and modifiyng/reading them from it would be cleaner approach.